# How should a DTO look like compared to an Entity

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, rest

Let's assume an application where there are leagues and teams inside of leagues, and teams can be in multiple leagues aswell. So we do have a many to many relationship.

**League Entity**

```
@Data
@Entity
public class League {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String name;
private String countryCode;
private SportType sportType;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "leagues")
    private List<Team> teams;
}
```

**Team Entity**

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Team {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String name;
private String logoUrl;
private SportType sportType;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "team_league",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "team_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "league_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private List<League> leagues;

}
```

I am now on the point where i need for example to create a new team, and upon creation, it needs a league to put in, which has to already exist. That means i need an endpoint which takes a list of `leagueIds` instead of a `List<League>`. So i assume i need to build a DTO. But how should the DTO look like and how would i implement the method that maps the DTO to an entity and saves it to the database.

**My idea of the TeamDTO**

```
@Data
public class TeamDTO {

private Long id;

private String name;
private String logoUrl;
private SportType sportType;
private List<Integer> leagueIds;
}
```

So instead of a `List<League>` i do have a `List<Integer> leagueIds` so that the endpoint can accept proper JSON. Is that correct?

Now i want to create the team in the database, IF the leagues of `List<Integer> leagueIds` are present in the database. So my question now is, when do i map to the entity.

**My idea of the implementation of the service**

```
public class TeamServiceImpl implements TeamService {

    @Autowired
    private LeagueRepository leagueRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TeamRepository teamRepository;

    @Override
    public Team createTeam(TeamDTO teamDTO) {
        List<Long> ids =
            teamDTO.getLeagueIds().stream().filter(leagueId ->
                leagueRepository.findById(leagueId).isPresent()).
                    collect(Collectors.toList();

        if (!ids.isEmpty()) {
            Team team = new Team();
            team.setName(teamDTO.getName());
            team.setLogoUrl(teamDTO.getLogoUrl());
            team.setSportType(teamDTO.getSportType());

            // do i actually need the League entities to set this?
            team.setLeagues(...);
            return team;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

- Most important question is: Is this the correct way?
- Should i use a mapper for DTO to entity and vice versa?
- Should i implement a mapper myself (i mean it only maps a few
  fields)?
- And on what place i would use the mapper, if i would implement one?

Comment: you should have a middle construct that points one to the team and one tot he league - then you only enter the team once and the league once and then link them multiple times

Comment: dont exactly understand what you mean

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you only want to save the team if it has leagues assigned that exist. It just sounds wrong to me i.e. some kind of bug is in your app if the league for an id does not exist. You should set a list of league references and rely on the FK-constraint to error if a wrong league id is used i.e. use something like this:

```
List<League> leagues =
            teamDTO.getLeagueIds().stream().map(leagueId ->
                leagueRepository.getOne(leagueId)).
                    collect(Collectors.toList());
team.setLeagues(leagues);
```

The DTO approach is fine and as long as it stays this simple, I guess using this custom implementation is good enough. If you have more complex requirements and want to make use of more efficient processing I would recommend you look into [Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) which was made for exactly this purpose, efficient mapping between JPA entities and DTOs.

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Team.class)
@UpdatableEntityView
public interface TeamDTO {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    void setName(String name);
    String getLogoUrl();
    void setLogoUrl(String logoUrl);
    SportType getSportType();
    void setSportType(SportType sportType);
    @UpdatableMapping
    @JsonIgnore
    List<LeagueDto> getLeagues();

    default List<Long> getLeagueIds() {
        return getLeagues().stream().map(LeagueDto::getId).collect(toList());
    }
    default void setLeagueIds(List<Long> ids) {
        getLeagues().clear();
        ids.stream().map(id -> evm().getReference(LeagueDto.class, id)).forEach(getLeagues()::add);
    }

    // This is a special context providing method
    EntityViewManager evm();

    @EntityView(League.class)
    interface LeagueDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`TeamDTO a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, TeamDTO.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<TeamDTO> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!

The saving part will then be as simple as this:

```
public class TeamServiceImpl implements TeamService {

    @Autowired
    private TeamRepository teamRepository;

    @Override
    public Team createTeam(TeamDTO teamDTO) {
        teamRepository.save(teamDTO);
        return teamRepository.getOne(teamDTO.getId());
    }
}
```

Due to the change-tracking implementation of Entity-Views, at any point in time it is clear what is dirty and will by default only flush these changes and avoid unnecessary select statements during flushing.